# Choosing correct MySQL query

Tags: mysql

In my project I am using one MySQL table to store **actual** information for every id (unnecessary fields are omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE  mytable (
  `id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

I need to update rows in this table and insert new `DateTime` **only** if this incoming `DateTime` is newer. But at the same time I do not know if the row with such `id` already exists in the table. Here is the pseudo-code of what I would like to achieve:

```
if id does not exist
    insert id and DateTime
else if newDateTime > DateTime
    update DateTime
```

- I tried to use replace, but as far as I know it is not possible to compare fields from within replace body.
- I tried to use update, but if row does not already exist - new information is not being inserted.

Is it possible to do something like this in one query? And if not - what could be the workaround?

PS: I do not think that I have permission to add stored procedures, so this should be a last resort.

Comment: fyi, it's recommended not to use reserved words for field names. otherwise, you'll have to always escape the 'DateTime' in backticks. I often use a 'stamp' field, or you could try 'date_time'.

Comment: @zanlok My project is using already existing database, I  can not change field names.

Comment: Is there no programming involved other than SQL.  What is sending this query?

Comment: okay, well that is an issue then. to avoid occasional query errors, you will want to escape that field name in backticks (grave), [like so](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) where it shows a table named 'interval'

Comment: @johnny It is a Java program, and I'm also using MyBatis for database things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this and it works. And I'm pretty proud of it.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`id`,`DateTime`)
VALUES ('your_new_id','your_new_DateTime')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `DateTime` = IF(`DateTime` < 'your_new_DateTime', 'your_new_DateTime', `DateTime`)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Will probably need to 'IF' every field that I want to update, but it should work.